# Como mapear correctamente una Query de un double en Firebase y Flutter - NoSuchMethodError: Class 'double' has no instance method '[]'

Tags: firebase, sql, flutter

Tengo una base de datos como la siguiente...

```
> > loteActual:     
> >          pesoInicial: 100.0
> >          ultimoCrec: 350.0`
```

Quiero hacer una consulta simple del pesoInicial (tipo double) y llevo horas sin lograr hacerlo ya que siempre me encuentro con el siguiente error:

> Exception has occurred. NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class
> 'double' has no instance method '[]'. Receiver: 350.0 Tried calling:
> )

Como se observa, pareciera que está recibiendo bien el dato (350.0), pero tiene algún tipo de estructura que no me permite leerlo.

El código que tengo para la consulta es el siguiente:

```
Future<double> cargarPesoInicial( String idEmpresa, String idEstanque) async {

  double pesoInicial; 

  Query resp = db.child('PATH.../loteActual/pesoInicial');

  return resp.once().then((snapshot) {

      if (snapshot.value == null) return pesoInicial;
      if (snapshot.value['error'] != null) return pesoInicial; 
      pesoInicial = snapshot.value;
      return pesoInicial;

      }
  );
}
```

Y el error aparece cuando hago el llamado al método...

```
double _pesoInicial;
_pesoInicial      = await loteActualBloc.cargarPesoInicial(idEmpresa, idEstanque);
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Se utilizó el código propuesto por @diegoveloper, de la siguiente forma:

```
Future<num> cargarPesoInicial( String idEmpresa, String idEstanque) async {

  num pesoInicial; 

  Query resp = db.child('PATH../loteActual/pesoInicial');
      final snapshot = await resp.once();
      print(snapshot.value);
      if (snapshot.value == null) return pesoInicial;
      pesoInicial = snapshot.value;
      return pesoInicial;

}
```

Sin embargo, en la linea de la asignación del valor al pesoInicial, aparece el siguiente error:

> Exception has occurred.
> _TypeError (type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el `then` es asíncrono, debes esperar el resultado.

```dart
Future<num> cargarPesoInicial( String idEmpresa, String idEstanque) async {

  num pesoInicial; 

  Query resp = db.child('PATH.../loteActual/pesoInicial');
      final snapshot = await resp.once();
      if (snapshot.value == null) return pesoInicial;
      pesoInicial = snapshot.value;
      return pesoInicial;
```

Pinta antes `snapshot.value` para ver si trae datos , no te olvides de cambiar esto también:

```dart
num _pesoInicial;
_pesoInicial      = await loteActualBloc.cargarPesoInicial(idEmpresa, idEstanque);
```

NOTA: No olvidar que el num puede reconocer valores `double` e `int`, pero una vez que la variable `num` obtiene el primer valor, y este valor es `int`, entonces actuará como `int.

Un workaround como mencionas es usar como tipo de dato `double` , el valor de resultado pasarlo a `String` y luego a `double` con `double.parse(value.toString())`

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111172/discussion-on-answer-by-diegoveloper-como-mapear-correctamente-una-query-de-un-d).

Comment: Tienes razón @diegoveloper. Hoy cambié el nombre de la variable por _pesoInicial y funcionó incluso asignando a double (sin necesidad del num). Debe ser que pesoInicial se está inicializando de en alg[un otro lado

Answer (score 0):

La solución más directa para leer un solo elemento **double** desde Firebase sin complicarse por los tipos de datos del snapshot es la siguiente...

```
Future<double> cargarPesoInicial() async {

  Query resp = db.child('PATH.../loteActual/pesoInicial');
    return resp.once().then((snapshot) => snapshot.value);
    
}
```

Si el elemento del query es de tipo **int**, la forma correcta es:

```
  Future<int> cargarNumAnimales() async {

  Query resp = db.child('PATH.../loteActual/pesoInicial');
    return resp.once().then((snapshot) => snapshot.value.round());
}
```

Comment: Por favor evita editar la respuesta del otro usuario para colocar tu propia solución, es mejor como lo hiciste ahora publicando tu propio aporte